# Barrier between a service using $http and controller using the service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Assume the following AngularJS service factory:

```
function Constants($http) {
    var constants = {
        someFields: someValues
    };
    $http({method: "GET", url: baseUrl + "/constants.json"}).success(
        function (data, status) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                constants[key] = value;
            });
        }
    );
    return constants;
}
```

It creates a service `Constants` with a set of constants in there. The constants are partly hardcoded and partly loaded from the `constants.json`, located on server (this logic is not discussable). This service is then used in a controller:

```
function SettingsController($scope, $rootScope, Constants) {
    $scope.someProperty = Constants.somePropertyFromConstantsJson;
    ...
```

I understand that `$http` calls are asynchronous. It means that there is no guarantee that the properties from `constants.json` in the example will be loaded and put to `Constants` before they are read in `SettingsController`.

How could I provide such a guarantee? How could I make `SettingsController` initialized only after the `$http` call in `Constants` is over?

UPD: The case I am talking about is a part of a bigger project. I want to avoid bigger changes all over the code base, so I need `Constants` to remain an object, properties of which are accessible through `.` or `[]`. That's why I'll consider options which doesn't fit this desire as a last resort.

UPD2: I checked the question marked as duplicate. Actually, I understand that `$http` is asynchronous operation, and I don't have intention to extract the local state of callbacks to the `Constants` factory constructor. The code of `Constants` constructor does that, but I am ok with refactoring it (until the type of `Constants` service and its properties is kept). I just wanted a way to make Angular create `Constants` service *after* the Http call is done. Some sort of asynchronous service initialization. I think my desire doesn't contradict with async nature of stuff, correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: You return the promise from the service instead of the data. Then the controller can use the promise and wait for it to resolve. This is a very common pattern and there should be ample examples here on SO.

Comment: It's not a desired option for me. I'd need to replace an object with promise in 100500 dependent modules over the application, which looks not good for a hotfix + I don't like an idea to have a promise for just a stupid set of constants, loaded once. I'd better avoid that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: @skapral set a property on `constants` equal to your AJAX call, then you can say `constants.myFunction().then(...)`. It won't change how the rest of your `constants` work across your modules

Answer (score 0):

Make the access to the constants async, instead of exposing the constants directly hide it behind a promise.

Something like that:

```js
function Constants($http, $q) {
  var constants = {
    someFields: someValues
  };

  const defer = $q.defer();

  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + "/constants.json"
  }).success(
    function(data, status) {
      angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
        constants[key] = value;
      });
    }
  ).then(() => defer.resolve(constants));


  return {
    whenLoaded: () => defer.promise;
  };
}


function SettingsController($scope, $rootScope, Constants) {
  Constants.whenLoaded().then((constants) => $scope.someProperty = constatns);
}
```

Comment: Don't even need to use a deferred, you can just treat `$q` as a regular `Promise` with `resolve` and `.then()`

Comment: As I said in the comments above, I'd better avoid making Constants a promise. Thanks for the answer though. If nobody proposes more alternatives, I will try it.

Comment: You can't get guarantee of async operation without making the access to it async.

Comment: @skapral This isn't making constants a promise.. it's making a *property* on constants a function that returns a promise

Comment: @felixmosh sure, I was just thinking of some way to make a service from promise value once it is resolved. See the question's update.